# Where do I put recreate() after changing a theme using preferences?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-theme, recreate

I have been trying to add a dark mode to my app and have mainly been using this site ([Tutorial](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%204/92_p_adding_settings_to_an_app.html)) to learn how to implement it. Everything works other than the theme does not change until I restart the app. After some research I have found that recreate() would be the correct way to fix this issue, but I do not know where to implement it.

Currently my oncreate method in the main activity looks like:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings_pref, false);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean contrastPref = sharedPref.getBoolean (Navigation.KEY_PREF_CONTRAST_SWITCH, false);
    setTheme(contrastPref? R.style.AppTheme_Dark : R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);........
```

With this just below the oncreate method

```
public static final String
        KEY_PREF_CONTRAST_SWITCH = "contrast_switch";
```

The fragment that holds the preference switch looks like this:

```
public  class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref, rootKey);
}}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: try to use theme with layout parent i think it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing theme from `SettingFragment` then call `getActivity().recreate()` from `SettingFragment`.

Comment: Hi, when I put that code in the onCreatePreferences method it just froze the fragment when I clicked on it. Do I have to make it so it only runs the "getActivity().recreate()" when the switch is triggered? If so how could I do that? Thanks for the help

Comment: `implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `SettingFragment ` so it overrides `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` and in that method you have to write `getActivity().recreate()`

Comment: For more details check - https://storiesandroid.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/android-settings-using-preference-fragments/

Comment: Hi again, i have updated my code to public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref, rootKey);

    }
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String rootKey){
        getActivity().recreate();
    }, it now doesnt freeze the fragment but it still doesnt recreate the activity. any ideas would be great thanks :)

Comment: Have you changed any setting in Setting screen?

Comment: By setting do you mean like the switch that I am using to switch the themes? If so I have clicked on it multiple times and it has moved between positions, but the theme has not changed

Comment: Verify that `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called when you click the switch

Comment: It doesn't seem like the method is called when I click the switch. I tried to make a message pop up, but it wouldn't show up when I clicked the switch.

Comment: Then you have to first identify why this method not called

Comment: the necessary code to fix it was "@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// Set up a listener whenever a key changes
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
// Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}". Thanks so much for being patient and helping me :)

Comment: Great! So your issue is fixed?